# Eclipse: Product Export error: The Product executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am exporting an Eclipse Plugin Project using Product Export Wizard, I have Eclipse Indigo 64 bit bits.

Everything works fine when I tried exporting it as a 64 bit project. But problems oocured when I tried exporting it into a 32bit project.

I have set the target platform, installed JRE 32bit, added all the required plugins, the program compiles and runs fine on a 32 bit JRE.

The product also seem to export successfully, however, when I tried running the .Exe, it throws an error "The Product executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library."

I have checked that the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar and org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502 both exists in the plugins folder. I have compared the plugins for the .product file with the runtime configuration plugins, everything seems fine, but I just could not start the .exe.

Please help..

Comment: Problem solved, turned out the .exe produced by Eclipse is somehow corrupted.

Comment: How you solved your problem please! I have exact the same problem with same environment!

Comment: Hi Govan, do you have a problem with the .exe? I did not really solve it, but rather I found a workaround. In my case, the .exe Eclipse generated was corrupted, it was trying to start 64bit Eclipse, instead of the 32bit present in the folder. I had to compile this project in another machine with only 32bit JRE and 32bit Eclipse, and replace my .exe with the one generated from a 32bit Eclipse, afterwards, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=361628), unpacking the org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_XXXXXXXX jar with the same name in the same directory (i.e. `plugins/`) fix the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with 64-bit Eclipse Mars SR1. The issue was that the exported product had a 64-bit launcher EXE instead of 32-bit.
The solutions are

1. Use the suggestion by @RKM and copy the launcher created by 32-bit Eclipse into your application.
2. Use 32-bit Eclipse directly for development and exporting product.